# formatted printing shows unexpected results

Tags: c, printf, string-formatting

i'm trying to create a formatted printing function and face this problem which i don't know whats its cause

## The idea

> using the power of **va_list**, i create a function **pf()** 
>   inside this function there's a **for** loop that i used to navigate cross the string **_Str** just after entering the **for** loop there's a **while** that test's on **(*conversion)  and  '%'** to print characters until meet the first **'%'**, is meted there's a **switch** to handle the arguments

### The code:

#### main.c

```
#include "base.h"

void pf(char* _Str, ...) 
{ 
    char* conversion; 
    //
    u_int i; 
    char* S; 

    //Initializing arguments 
    //
    va_list arg; 
    va_start(arg, _Str); 

    for(conversion = _Str; *conversion != '\0'; conversion++) 
    { 
        while( *conversion != '%' ) 
        { 
            putchar(*conversion);
            conversion++; 
        }//end while
        conversion++; 
        //arguments
        //
        switch(*conversion) 
        {   
            case 'c' : i = va_arg(arg, int);        //char argument
                        putchar(i);
                        break; 
            case 'd' : i = va_arg(arg, int);        //Decimal/Integer argument
                        if(i < 0) { i = -i; putchar('-');} 
                        puts(convert(i, 10));
                        break; 
            case 'o': i = va_arg(arg,u_int); //Octal representation
                        puts(convert(i, 8));
                        break; 
            case 's': S = va_arg(arg, char *);      //string argument
                        puts(S); 
                        break; 
            case 'x': i = va_arg(arg, u_int); //Hexadecimal representation
                        puts(convert(i, 16));
                        break; 
        }//end switch   
    }//end for
    //
    //
    va_end(arg); 
}// end pf()
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    pf("test1\vtest2 %d %o %x %c%c",10,512,1024,'O','K'); 
    return 0;
}
```

#### base.h

```
#ifndef BASE_H_
 #define BASE_H_
  #ifndef EOF // (EOF) - End Of File character. (-1)
   #define EOF (-1)
   #endif// EOF 
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>


 #include<stdarg.h> 
  typedef unsigned int u_int;

    void pf(char*, ...);            //  Our printf function
    char* convert(u_int, int);      // Convert integer number into octal, hex, etc.
#endif // BASE_H_
```

## The problem

when give arguments to **pf**.the upper code works fine and as expected

> Using arguments
>
> ### Compiling

```
[ar.lnx@host printf] $ make
Building objects..
gcc -c -o main.o main.c -I. -Wall 
Building the application core..
gcc -o x main.o -I. -g
Finish.
[ar.lnx@host printf] $ ./x
test1
     test2 10
 1000
 400
 OK[ar.lnx@host printf]
```

But when not give any arguments  to **pf**, it shows unexpected result!
for example trying to test on

```
pf("test3\vtest4");
```

> not using arguments(unexpected result)
>
> ### Compiling

```
[ar.lnx@host printf] $ make
Building objects..
gcc -c -o main.o main.c -I. -Wall 
Building the application core..
gcc -o x main.o base.o  -I. -g
Finish.
[ar.lnx@host printf] $ ./x
test3
     test4 �@�@@@@@@@@@@@\@@@@�@@@@@���������h�����
                                                   ��������X��� ����@ ����zRx
                                                                            ����*zRx
                                                                                   $���PF▒J
                                                                                           �?▒;*3$"D���
[ar.lnx@host printf] $
```

i have no idea about how did the program show those results, someone help me understand how

Comment: Name starting with an underscore and followed by an uppercase Letter or another underscore are reserved for the implementation. Do not use them! Ans what is `u_int`? Why not use `unsigned`? Don't obfuscate your code.

Comment: I removed the `c++` tag, `c++` and `c` are not the same language.

Comment: Your inner `while` loop is not checking for the null terminator at all, so it can loop past the end of `_Str` into surrounding memory.  Also, is there a reason why you are implementing formatted output manually in the first place, instead of using [`vprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf) or equivalent instead?

Comment: You are incrementing `conversion` more than once in the loop. Perfect recipe to miss the nul-terminator.

Comment: Note: `puts(convert(i, 10));` also prints a `'\n'`, something that `printf("%d", some_int)` does not do.

Comment: @RemyLebeau @Egune Sh i guess you didn't understand how my code works, i use `for(conversion = _Str; *conversion != '\0'; conversion++)` to check on '\0'

Comment: @A010010001: That is in your **outer** loop, but your **inner** loop is not looking for `'\0'` at all, but it needs to.

Answer (score 3):

Your inner `while` loop is not checking for the null terminator, so it can loop past the end of `_Str` into surrounding memory.  Your code fails if a format specifier does not exist at the very end of `_Str` (in your example, your failing string does not even have any `%` characters in it at all).  So the `while` loop does not break unless it *happens* to encounter a `%` in memory outside of the string.  Until then, it just keeps printing out the bytes of that surrounding memory, which is what you are seeing in your output.

Try this instead:

```
void pf(char* _Str, ...) 
{ 
    char* conversion; 
    //
    int i; 
    u_int ui; 
    char* S; 

    //Initializing arguments 
    //
    va_list arg; 
    va_start(arg, _Str); 

    for(conversion = _Str; *conversion != '\0'; conversion++) 
    { 
        while( (*conversion != '%') && (*conversion != '\0') ) 
        { 
            putchar(*conversion);
            conversion++; 
        }//end while

        if (*conversion == '\0') 
            break;

        conversion++;  // skip '%'

        //arguments
        //
        switch (*conversion) 
        {   
            case 'c' : i = va_arg(arg, int); //char argument
                        putchar(i);
                        break; 
            case 'd' : i = va_arg(arg, int); //Decimal/Integer argument
                        if (i < 0) { i = -i; putchar('-');} 
                        puts(convert(i, 10));
                        break; 
            case 'o': ui = va_arg(arg, u_int); //Octal representation
                        puts(convert(ui, 8));
                        break; 
            case 's': S = va_arg(arg, char *); //string argument
                        puts(S); 
                        break; 
            case 'x': ui = va_arg(arg, u_int); //Hexadecimal representation
                        puts(convert(ui, 16));
                        break; 
            case '%': putchar('%'); //percent literal
                        break; 
            default : putchar('%'); // anything else
                        putchar(*conversion);
                        break; 
        }//end switch   
    }//end for

    va_end(arg); 
}// end pf()
```

That being said, there is no need to implement formatted output manually in this example (especially since you are not implementing all of the options that formatting supports).  You should use [`vprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf) instead, let it do the hard work for you, eg:

```
void pf(char* _Str, ...) 
{ 
    va_list arg; 
    va_start(arg, _Str); 
    vprintf(_Str, arg);​
    va_end(arg); 
}
```

Comment: i'm trying to understand how formatted printing works, so that's the main reason of upper code. @RemyLebeau can you please tell me the problem without using printf sisters

Comment: @A010010001: I already told you what the problem is. It is stated in the first sentence of my answer above: "*Your inner `while` loop is not checking for the null terminator*". It needs to. I have updated my answer with a fixed example.

Comment: can you test the you fixed example using `pf("test4\vtest3 "); ` , something seems incorrect...